# Append content of array to Collections.Generic.List

Tags: .net

if i try to

```
$g = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char[]]]@()
$g.AddRange([char[]]@('1','2'))
```

i get this

```
Cannot convert argument "collection", with value: "System.Char[]", for "AddRange" to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Char[]]"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break it down:

```
Cannot convert argument "collection"
```

The compiler can't convert between one type and another for the parameter called "collection"

```
with value: "System.Char[]"
```

Means you are passing a Char Array (`System.Char[]`)

```
for "AddRange"
```

You are passing the Char Array to the AddRange method.

```
 to type "System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Char[]]"
```

AddRange is expecting an IEnumerable (e.g. List or array) of Char Arrays

So, cant convert from Char Array to an Array/List of Char Arrays

So either:

- You are calling the wrong method and should be calling Add not AddRange
- or the type of your collection should be Char not Char[]

Comment: ~~"Char" is not a collection, its a single byte . the question is about how to accomplish this, more efficiently than with `Add` loop~~

Comment: $g = [System.Collections.Generic.List[char[]]]@() 
Is a List of Char Arrays
You are trying to add a Char Array to the list using the AddRange method which expects a collection of Char Arrays